# How to use packer to build AMI without SSH

Tags: ssh, amazon-ami, packer

I would like to use packer to build AMI's where SSH is not running. This will be for immutable infrastructure. We will be building base / golden images and then building more streamlined images from the base image but, ultimately, I don't want SSH or any other means of remote access to the image. Can packer do this?

Comment: If ssh is off, how do you intend to build the images? Or do you want ssh to be turned off at the end of the build process?

Comment: At the end of the build is fine. Ideally I want an image that once deployed it is immutable. If something doesn't work right then we destroy it and bake an altered image. This is partially for increased security and partially for compliance reasons that the machines do not have remote access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Packer's ability to do this. However, you could use AWS Security Groups to control SSH access to your EC2 instances after they've been spun up using your AMIs.

Just create a Security Group that denies all ingress connections, and place your EC2 instance into it.